# How to insert extra rows into the same table using cursor and increase a column value of the new records

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, sql-insert

In SQL Server, I want for every `SELECT` result to insert three new rows in the same table with `itemid = max itemid + counter` every time.

For example:

```
(ItemID, PackageID, ItemTypeID, ServiceID, ItemName, CreatedDate) 
VALUES
    (17891, 5352, 7007, 2011, N'Firewall''s Lan NIC', '11/11/2015 6:50:51  PM'),
    (17892, 5352, 7008, 2011, N'Firewall''s Mng NIC', '11/11/2015 6:50:51 PM'),
    (17893, 5352, 7006, 2011, N'Firewall''s Wan NIC', '11/11/2015 6:50:51 PM')
```

- ItemID = primary key
- PackageID = from select query
- ItemTypeID = as it is
- ServiceID = from select query
- ItemName = as it is
- CreatedDate = now

I am trying this one to loop through `SELECT` results.

```
DECLARE @item_id int, 
@package_id nvarchar(50),
@itemtype_id varchar(80), 
@item_name varchar(80), 
@service_id nvarchar(50);

DECLARE @message nvarchar(150)
PRINT '-------- Service Items Report --------';

DECLARE serviceitems_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT PackageID, ItemID
FROM ServiceItems
WHERE ItemTypeID = '7004' 
ORDER BY ItemID;

OPEN serviceitems_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM serviceitems_cursor 
INTO @package_id, @itemtype_id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT ' '
    SELECT @message = '-----Service Items from serviceitems_cursor  - packageId: ' + @package_id
    PRINT @message
        -- I want here to add three new rows 
        -- For every new item row I want itemid to be SELECT MAX(ItemID) + thecounter  FROM ServiceItems  
        -- /thecounter is the new counter after each insertion
    FETCH NEXT FROM serviceitems_cursor 
    INTO @package_id, @itemtype_id
END 
CLOSE serviceitems_cursor;
DEALLOCATE serviceitems_cursor;
```

How could I perform all new records to have current max itemid + the counter

```
SELECT MAX(ItemID) + 1  FROM ServiceItems )
```

For, example if the max itemId is 17890, new records will have

```
 17891, 17892, 17893
```

(first three rows insertion)

```
17894, 17895, 17896
```

(second three rows insertion) etc.

Comment: It sounds like you want a trigger, not a cursor.

Comment: Ok  @GordonLinoff  let me try something with triggers.

Comment: Or do you just want an `identity` column?

Answer (score 0):

By two ways you can achieve this,

(1) Get the max of ItemId and put it in one local variable.

```
Declare @max_itemid int =(select max (itemid ) from services )
```

Already through cursor loop you have all the remaining column values in local variables. (From select query )

Now all you need to do is Insert. (Using union all )

```
Insert into services (
<column list >)
Select @max_itemid+1 as item_id, @pkg, @service_id, get date()
UNION ALL 
Select @max_itemid+2 as item_id, @pkg, @service_id, get date()
UNION ALL 
Select @max_itemid+3 as item_id, @pkg, @service_id, get date()
```

All the codes mentioned above should reside inside while @@fetch status block

(2) Approach two is simple, you don't need to get the max and increment it every time, make item_id as identity column. (Not sure your business needs accordingly you decide )